# UITextView Clickable, almost like UIButton

Tags: ios

I have a `UITextView` with a lot of text in it, and customized the way I need it. I was wondering, is there a way to make it clickable and then navigate to a new `UIViewController`?

I was searching for this, seems like only way is to have an invisible `UIButton` covering it?

Comment: Why don't you want to have an invisible UIButton covering it?

Comment: It's not the right way, don't want to put too much weight on the GUI unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a UITapGestureRecogniser to your textview. Either in interface builder, or in your code.

```
UITapGestureRecogniser *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myfunction:)]:
[mytextview addGestureRecogniser:tap];
[mytextview setEditable:NO];
[mytextview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[tap release];
```

Edit: Thanks Nekto

Comment: + don'f forget to disable editing of `UITextView` but enable `userInteraction`

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` does not declare the selector `addGestureRecognizer`, so I use this instead:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textViewTapped:)];
NSArray *gestureRecognizers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:tap];
[textView setGestureRecognizers:gestureRecognizers];
[textView setEditable:NO];
[textView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using interface builder, you can set the TextViews class as UIControl. You can then control drag from it to any IBAction.